# Update fields in nested objects in firestore documents without removing other nested objects?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a flutter project where I use Firebase Firestore as my database.
Currently, I am having trouble with a cloud function. This function should update a nested object in my database.

The structure looks like this:

```
{
"plannings" : {
    "0" : {
        "finalSchedule": null, 
        "teacherName": "----", 
        "endDate": "8-11-2020", 
        "learnerAvailabilities": {
            "3vLYq8Zlm6Z2KkGDbdu3rwQWMTd2": null, 
            "DTtN4j1fngfjZM3p8v5JVyc7hrn2": null, 
            "ekzj2Iy8JngtourPvHQyQAHJx563": null, 
            "Ss9QV7qFVvXBzTe3R6lmHkMBEWn1": null, 
            "tzEe2jhcr7hn1X1gu7c8BfuyO5a2": null, 
            "otlqIURWB5SZeChzhoaQOmNEi6m2": null,
        }, 
        "name": "----", 
        "id": "#5a066",
        }
    },
"Learners" : {},
"etc..." : {},
}
```

I want to be able to update the value of every 'learnerAvailability' (ID) individually. So I tried this:

```
school.update({
    [`plannings.${key}.learnerAvailabilities.${userUID}`]: newSchoolUserAvailabilityObject,
});
```

But when I do so, every ID, except for the one changed, is removed.
And "finalSchedule", "teacherName", "endDate", "name", "id" are also gone.
So I end up with something like this when I change the value of "3vLYq8Zlm6Z2KkGDbdu3rwQWMTd2":

```
{
"plannings" : {
    "0" : {
        "learnerAvailabilities": {
            "3vLYq8Zlm6Z2KkGDbdu3rwQWMTd2": (new value), 
        }, 
        }
    },
"Learners" : {},
"etc..." : {},
}
```

I also can't just replace the "plannings" object entirely every time, because that causes trouble when two updates (.update) are happening at (almost) the same time.

Comment: As an FYI, you have "Plannings" with a capital in your document, but your code shows "plannings" with no capital.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry for the confusion. It should all with lower a 'p'. I edited it. This is not the issue though.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the specific *before* and *after* states of the document using screenshots, so it is very clear what happened.

Comment: @DougStevenson I did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "plannings" field started out as an **array**, but then you updated it to be a **map**.  Firestore doesn't provide a way to update array items by index.  If you want to modify an array item, you have to read the entire document, modify the array in memory, then update the document with the new contents of the array.

Comment: So changing it so that It is a map from the beginning should also fix it?

Comment: Sure, if you'd rather have a map there in the first place, do that.  But a map indexed by integers might not be what you really want.  It's up to you.

Comment: Ah okay, Thanks a lot :D. I'll try that.